# Hide element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want is to hide certain element using Javascript. Specifically, I want this element showed only if the URL contains the text 'cli'. I tried that using next code

```js
    var regex = window.location.href;
if(regex.indexOf('cli')>-1){
$(window).load(function() {
    $("[routerlinkactive]")[1].remove();
});
}
```

The routerlnkactive parts works separatedly. That is, if no if statement is written, it is always removed. But I want that to work only with that URL. How could I do that?

Doesn't seem to be working neither with xxx.html or with xxx.html?cli=30

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the indexOf() function. So something like

```
 var regex = window.location.href;
 if(regex.indexOf('cli')>-1){ //if cli is there
        $("[routerlinkactive]")[1].hide(); //hide
  }
```

It will return -1 if not found, and will return the string position number if found (starting at 0).

Also, you should use `.hide()` to hide, not remove.

UPDATE:

since you are saying its still not working, i have just checked, and this works:

```
var regex = "xxxxxx.com?cli=50";
if(regex.indexOf('cli')>-1){
   alert(true);
}else{
   alert(false);
}
```

So replace alert() with the hide() function and make sure the html is correctly referenced (even though you said that was working okay?). And the value of regex should be  `window.location.href`. 
Try adding and removing 'cli' and youll see the difference.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. It does the same with xxxx.html and with xxxx.html?cli=30

And I'm using remove as the hide() function of Jquery didn't seem to be working

Comment: please update your code in question and ill take a look.

Comment: For some reason, hide doesn't work not even using Web Console. But using remove works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Remove()` is not the right choice, that will remove the element from the DOM.

Use `hide()` and `show()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide your element by default on page load
    $("[routerlinkactive]")[1].hide();
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("cli") > -1) {
        //If URL has "cli" then show that element.
        $("[routerlinkactive]")[1].show();
    }
});
```

[Reference of indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)